# Implicit function, real analysis homework question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-differentiation

Consider the equation $xe^{y}+ye^{x}=0$

(a) Prove that this equation defines $y$ as a $C^{\infty}$ function of $s$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$

(b) Ley $y=g(x)$ be this implicitly defined function. Find $g'(0)$ and $g''(0)$

(c) Explain the appearance of the curve $xe^{y}+ye^{x}=0$ near $(0,0)$

I think (a) is the one I need most help with. Really appreciate if someone give me a hint or explain to me how to prove it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This is a very typical homework assignment. This means you probably did something similar in class. See what you did there and attempt to use that here. Then, post your question about what causes problems.

Comment: The title of your question has the phrase "implicit function".  Have you looked at the statement of the implicit function theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

$F(x, y) = xe^y + ye^x; \tag {1}$

then

$F_y(x, y) = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x, y) = xe^y + e^x, \tag{2}$

and evaluating this at $(0, 0)$ we find that

$F_y(0, 0) = 1, \tag{3}$

and now by the *implicit function theorem*, more about which may be found in the wikipedia page of the same name, we can assert the existence of a smooth function $g(x)$ with $y=g(x)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $x = 0$, such that

$F(x, y) = xe^y + ye^x = xe^{g(x)} + g(x)e^x = 0 \tag{4}$

for $x \in U$.  This answers part (a).  Note that (4) implies $g(0) = 0$.

For part (b), we differentiate (4) with respect to $x$, yielding

$e^y + xy'e^y + y'e^x + ye^x = 0, \tag{5}$

or

$y'(xe^y + e^x) + e^y + ye^x = 0, \tag{6}$

which may readily be solved for $y'$:

$y' = -\dfrac{e^y + ye^x}{xe^y + e^x}. \tag{7}$

In order to find $y''$, we can in fact differentiate (7) with respect to $x$, but I think it is a little easier to work directly with (6):

$y''(xe^y + e^x) + y'(e^y + xy'e^y + e^x) + y'e^y + y'e^x + ye^x = 0, \tag{8}$

which we re-write in a manner which consolidates the terms containing $y'$:

$y''(xe^y + e^x) + y'(e^y + xy'e^y + e^x + e^y + e^x) + ye^x = 0, \tag{9}$

or

$y''(xe^y + e^x) + y'(2e^y + xy'e^y + 2e^x) + ye^x = 0, \tag{10}$

from which

$y'' = -\dfrac{y'(2e^y + xy'e^y + 2e^x) + ye^x}{xe^y + e^x}. \tag{11}$

Note that all the operations in the above are well-defined in a neighborhood of $(0, 0)$ since
$xe^y + e^x = 1 \ne 0$ at that point.  From (7) we have

$g'(0) = y'(0) = -1, \tag{12}$

and (11) yields

$g''(0) = y''(0) = 4. \tag{13}$

We have thus dispensed with part (b).

As for (c), there's not much to *explain*, really; it's more a matter of *describing*, in rough terms, the overall features of the curve $F(x, y) = xe^y + ye^x = 0$ near $(0, 0)$.  With the information we have at hand, this is a straightforward matter, since the function $y = g(x)$ satisfies $F(x, g(x)) = 0$.  Thus we can deduce the properties of the curve $F(x, y) = xe^y + ye^x = 0$ from those we know of $g(x)$.  We see that the curve in question passes through the point $(0, 0)$, and that it has slope $-1$ there, in keeping with the fact that $\nabla F(0, 0) = (1, 1)$, normal to the tangent line $y = -x$ to $y = g(x)$ at $(0, 0)$, and the fact that $x$ and $y$ must be of opposite signs when $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$.  The fact that $g''(0) = 4 > 0$ indicates that the slope $g'(x)$ is increasing as we move away from $x = 0$, so the curve $F(x, y) = 0$ is apparently concave upward at $(0, 0)$, but apart from a more exhaustive analysis, we can say little else.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so clear!! I will read very carefully. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ user220055:  Glad you found it helpful, and thanks for the kind words!  And thanks for the "acceptance"! By the way, not to be greedy, but "upvotes" are also appreciated as well! ;-)

Comment: @ user220055:  hey, thanks again!  Cheers!